# C#: ListBox SelectedIndex changes itself when method returns

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a problem with ListBox in c#(winforms). This ListBox contains the list of files(only pictures) in a specified directory like this:

```
private ListBox FileList = new ListBox();
private List<string> Directories = new List<string>
{
  @"some path",
  @"some other path",
  @"..."
};
private List<string> Pictures;

private int selectedDirectory = 0;
public int SelectedDirectory
{
  get { return selectedDirectory; }
  set
  {
    //the list of pictures is returned correctly
    Pictures = GetPictures(Directories[value]); 
    selectedDirectory = value;
    EventHandler handler = this.DirectoryChanged;
    // noone who subscribed to the event
    // changes FileList.SelectedItem or FileList.SelectedIndex
    if(handler != null)
      handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    this.SelectedPicture = Pictures.Count == 0 ? -1 : 0;
  }


this.DirectoryChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
  FileList.Items.Clear();
  FileList.Items.AddRange(Pictures);
};

private int selectedPicture
public int SelectedPicture
{
  get { return selectedPicture; }
  set
  {
    selectedPicture = value;
    if(value != -1)
      PictureBox1.Load(Pictures[value]);
    FileList.SelectedIndex = value;
  }
}

// after this method returns, FileList.SelectedIndex changes to a random value depending on what Directory was selected before the change
private void MainFormKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad5)
    SelectedDirectory --;
  if(e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2)
    SelectedDirectory ++;
} // the value of SelectedIndex changes after leaving this exact line
```

I tried to debug it and the result was that from setting the value of `FileList.SelectedIndex` in `this.SelectedPicture` it remained 0 until `MainFormKeyDown` returned. EDIT: I forgot to mention that at that point `FileList.SelectedIndex` changes to a random value instead of `0` or `-1` as it should.

What can cause this kind of behaviour and how can I solve it?

I have checked if I change the value anywhere else in the code or in any event subscription but not.

I also tried using `ListView`, but the result remained the same.

Now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What event is MainFormKeyDown hooked into in the MainForm?

Comment: I don't understand: MainFormKeyDown changes SelectedDirectory . This triggeres the setter. Here this.SelectedPicture gets changed, triggering its setter. There you have FileList.SelectedIndex = value; No?

Comment: @TaW I forgot to mention that FileList.SelectedIndex chages to a _random value_ not _0_ or _-1_ as it should. Sorry.

Comment: @kmcnamee KeyDown event, edited the post to fit KeyDown, my mistake.

Comment: Hm, hard to tell. Could it be that the listbox has focus and the keyboard action triggers a selection change?

Comment: @TaW Probably, it is, since when I load a directory's content changing to that from upwards(pressing numpad2) it selects an item starting with "2", and when I change to that from downwards(pressing numpad5) it changes to an item starting with "5". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the listbox has focus it could be that the KeyDown event fires the user lets go of the key and the KeyUp event fires and the list box changes its selectedIndex.  Did you try changing to the KeyUp event and setting

```
e.Handled = true;
```

[Handled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If i hold down the key KeyDown will fire a few times.  You can put a Debug.WriteLine to see this if you hold down a key it will fire a few times.  Another reason to use KeyUp.

Comment: Your solution works nice. The problem was that it switched to an item which's name starts with the letter I pressed on the keyboard to switch to that directory. You can learn something new every day, thanks for this one :)